# Why does event listener change the current object?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I've been using JS for a little bit ( 9 months), and was writing a game when I realized this. I had a `Level` object, which had a property `player`. The player needed to react to key events, so I wrote this up:

```
export class Level{
  constructor(){
    this.player = new Player();

    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyHandeler);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyHandeler);
  }
  keyHandeler(event){
    const down = event.type == 'keydown';
    switch(event.keyCode){
      case 37: this.player.keys.left   = down; break;
      case 38: this.player.keys.up     = down; break;
      case 39: this.player.keys.right  = down; break;
      case 40: this.player.keys.bottom = down; break;
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I ran this code I kept getting an error along the lines of `Can not read property "keys" of undefined`, meaning that `this.player` was undefined. I then logged `this` inside of the `keyHandeler` function, and got the window object. I can see how this might make sense, but the function is still a part of `Level`. If this is just the way it is, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to bind `this` to the class like `this.keyhandler = this.keyHandler.bind(this)` in the constructor

Comment: "*the function is still a part of Level*" - it might be defined as a part of the `Level` class, but that just means it's stored on `Level.prototype`. It is not bound to a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `handleEvent` method to your object, and then pass the object itself as the event handler.

This makes your object implement the *EventListener Interface*, which means it qualifies for use as the event handler, instead of using a function.

```
export class Level{
  constructor(){
    this.player = new Player();

    window.addEventListener('keydown', this);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this);
  }

  handleEvent(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
    case "keydown": case "keyup":
      this.keyHandler(event);
      break
    }
  }

  keyHandeler(event){
    const down = event.type == 'keydown';
    switch(event.keyCode){
      case 37: this.player.keys.left   = down; break;
      case 38: this.player.keys.up     = down; break;
      case 39: this.player.keys.right  = down; break;
      case 40: this.player.keys.bottom = down; break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now  when the event occurs, the `handleEvent` method will be invoked with `this` as the instance you assigned as the handler.

There can be certain improvements on organizing this, but I mostly wanted to build on your example.